# Best practice - pages - ACF or inline coding

Tags: customization, pages, templates

I would like to migrate the following website to WordPress (http://www.absoluteblast.com.au).

What is the best practice to implement the service pages?
--> I thought to create a custom template which is in use for all single services.
But I'm pretty sure, that after migrating this website to WP, my task will be to improve the website, i.e. also the service pages. That means, that the service pages won't have exactly the same layout, so we can't just pull the content out of the editor field. So what will be the best practice, to make it ready for the future?

Had these thoughts:

1. Custom Template for each service (all hardcoded within the template)
2. Custom Template for each service, combined with Advanced Custom Fields. That means the certain template pulls out the content of all the Advanced fields, and generates the page through that.
3. Inline coding for each service within TinyMCE Editor (defining containers etc. there, and for content pulling text blocks inside. Simple, but not really professional or is it?!)

Since I'm pretty new to WordPress, I would really appreciate your help.
Hope that is all clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#3 is fastest, #2 is probably slowest and therefore most expensive, #1 is likely the middle ground.

It's really a function of budget and update frequency. How often will these pages be updated? Who will be updating them? If it's you the developer then you build it for yourself or another developer. If it's a client requirement to be able to update it themselves - well, find out what they mean by 'update' (are they planning to merely add/swap out images or add entire new pages?), make this process as smooth for them as possible, and train them.

Comment: Hey, it's a bit late, but I just noticed now that I missed it to say thanks. So now: Thank you! That helped me quite a lot.

I ended up with the first choice because you are right, it's only a question about time management and whether the client wants to add features himself.